# DatabaseException CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, ubuntu, jdbc

I use Ubuntu & Net-beans. I make a java desktop database  application from Netbeans wizard.  I use MySQL database which I can open & run query from its Services → Databases. When I run it I got the Exception below. When I clean & Build the Project run jar file, same Exception.  I have installed  Windows in the same machine dual boot way, and also have the same MySQL database & Java.  When I run the jar file I make using Ubuntu Netbeans, it perfectly run in Windows and show the database data. I did the other way also, I make the same java application in Windows Netbeans using the same database and it run perfectly both withing the Netbeans and jar file.  But when I try to run it in Ubuntu, both in Netbeans & jar file show the below Exception.

> [TopLink Info]: 2012.01.29 11:16:58.898--ServerSession(285416048)--TopLink, version: Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))
>   Jan 29, 2012 11:16:59 AM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
>   SEVERE: Application class customerrecordsu.CustomerRecordsUApp failed to launch
>   Local Exception Stack: 
>   Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Error Code: 0
>       at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:305)

```
... lot of more
```

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:427)

```
... lot of more
```

**Below is part of 'my.cnf' file removing comments.**

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306

skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

below is part of persistance.xml file

```
  <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBusinessRecords"/>
  <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
```

Netbeans wizard use JPA, & Top Link.  I make a program without wizard by pure Java, it worked perfectly in Ubuntu as expected and show the database data.  That program is below. Both above and below use same Java MySQL connector.jar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int id = 0;
    String name = null;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBusinessRecords";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "5843");
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("A database connection has been establised!");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from COUNTRIES");
            while(rs.next()){
            id = rs.getInt(1);
            name = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("id = " + id + " Name = " + name);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem" + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            con = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my system

java version "1.7.0_01"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)
Ubuntu 11.10.  OS type 64 bit
MySQL Version- MySQL 5.1.58-1ubuntu1
MySQL Client Version 5.1.58
Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

I read the Q & A more then 15 in this site with same question, but that now one helped me.  Please help me.

Comment: It seems soemthing wrong with IP/Port. Did you ping and check?

Comment: When I ping PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms

Comment: How can I check it?telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
=
5.1.58-1ubuntu1.a.a}tKZeP@1rlG_&?I3Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Is your MySQL service running in the background? It seems like your service isn't running.M not sure about Ubuntu, but in windows, you can start the service from services.msc.

Comment: on browser write `http://localhost:3306` and let me know what you get...

Comment: =���
5.1.58-1ubuntu1�5���a/b#'7!=�ÿ÷��������������Q_giZeo}G(0Y���ÿ„Got packets out of order

Comment: Dear Shashank Kadne How I find it?

Comment: in linux  sudo service mysql status

mysql start/running, process 1019

Comment: are you using GlassFish Server on Netbeans??

Comment: restart the server that you are using and try again... There is problem in your server...

Comment: Then why my pure java cord works in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have restart the server several times It not work. by  sudo service mysql restart

Comment: GlassFish Server? I don't think so. How can I find I Use it? Sory I am not a java expert;)

Comment: Sory Yes in netbeans Servers Glassfish Server 3.1 added. Shall I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBusinessRecords";
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:
>   a non-existant SOCKS proxy
>   bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
>   You can try bind-address = 0.0.0.0 or jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MyBusinessRecords"

Comment: Tanaks Yongxin, Both options not work. When I log as super user in Ubuntu by sudo and run the build jar file it works.  Also when I open Netbeans as root also it works fine. Must be problem with JPA or Top- Link.

Answer (score 0):

Try Java 1.6.  I had a similar issue and changed back to Java 1.6 (I had upgraded to 1_7) and the issue went away. Probably need a different toplink or OracleDriver release for 1_7.